# Calculate the variance of a 2D matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I make a function that calculates the variance of a 2D matrix using loops i and j...where do I start?

Comment: First, you need to write down an equation (or algorithm) that describes what you want to calculate...

Comment: Also, it's not very Matlab to use a loop if you could just use `var(array(:))` and calculate the variance in one step.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use loop variables in Matlab since this is inevitably much slower than using inbuilt (vectorized) functions.

The function `var` calculates the variance of a matrix column-wise. With `(:)` you convert a 2D matrix into a single column.

Or as [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708038/calculate-the-variance-of-a-2d-matrix-matlab#comment5199879_4708038) pointed out, use:

```
var(array(:))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = var(double(twoDarray(:)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reshape in order to transform image as a vector. After that, you could calculate the variance using:

```
 v1 = var(reshape(im2(:,:),[],1));
```